# EF 6 optional parameter stored procedure with output parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am calling a stored procedure with optional params with an output parameter like below. I have tried `ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>` and `ExecuteSqlCommand`. Both throws an error.

The stored procedure has these params with most of them being optional:

```
    @Debug          CHAR(1)      = 'N', 
    @Yr             VARCHAR(4),
    @Collection_ID  INT          = NULL, 
    @SortOrder      VARCHAR(100) = ' ',     
    @SrchDates      VARCHAR(100) = '',      
    @FixedFormat    CHAR(1)      = 'C',     
    @ExtrctStrtFg   CHAR(1)      = 'D',     
    @APP_ID         INT          = NULL,
    @MatchFound     CHAR(1)      = 'N' OUTPUT
```

My call is:

```
var retVal = frlentities.Database.SqlQuery<string>("exec pr_storedproc @Yr = 2000,@ExtrctStrtFg='F', @APP_ID=1234, @MatchFound OUTPUT;");
```

This complains that the fourth parameter `@sortorder` is provided as an output parameter. The same works when I do not have an output parameter and the I am getting a list with other stored procedures. Hope there is some way around this. I can provide all parameter by importing the stored procedure. But some stored procedures have too many parameters. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide exact error message when using output parameter? Usually parameter values are provided through `SqlParameter` array instead of assign it directly in query string of `SqlQuery<T>`.

Comment: "The formal parameter "@SortOrder" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output."

Comment: And the MatchFound is also declared as: 

            var MatchFound = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "MatchFound",
                Size = 1,
                DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
            };